# Staggered GridView with ScrollListener

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, gridview

I want to create a grid-like in Pinterest or Wish Android applications.
I already found some solutions like http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/

But all the solutions that I found don't have a ScrollListener, that I am using to detect reaching the bottom and loading new content.

Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: I have done that, check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17148142/1124691

Answer (score 2):

Try my solution of wrapping a scroll view around recycler view and then adding scroll listener to the scroll view: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43780074/6662058

Answer (score 1):

how about try this open source library.
https://github.com/huewu/PinterestLikeAdapterView

It is implemented based on android internal adapter view codes and provide its own OnScrollerListener interface just like android's original one.

Answer (score 0):

For all thoses who need to set a scroll listener on the StaggeredGridView, here is my forked version that add the support for this feature -> https://github.com/GoMino/StaggeredGridView