# How to add data into bottom of Android StaggeredGridView and not go back top?

Tags: android

I'm use [StaggeredGridView](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView) in my project,and I add data into the staggered grid view when scroll to bottom,but the grid view had go back top.I do not want it to go back top.

The following is the onChanged method in StaggeredGridView, how to modify it?

Please help me to resolve this problem,thanks very much!

```
private class AdapterDataSetObserver extends DataSetObserver {

    private Parcelable mInstanceState = null;

    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        mDataChanged = true;
        mItemCount = mAdapter.getCount();

     // TODO: Consider matching these back up if we have stable IDs.
        mRecycler.clearTransientViews();

        if (mHasStableIds) {
            // Clear all layout records and recycle the views
            mLayoutRecords.clear();
            recycleAllViews();

            // Reset item bottoms to be equal to item tops
            final int colCount = mColCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
                mItemBottoms[i] = mItemTops[i];
            }
        }

        // reset list if position does not exist or id for position has changed
        if(mFirstPosition > mItemCount-1 || mAdapter.getItemId(mFirstPosition) != mFirstAdapterId){
            mFirstPosition = 0;
            Arrays.fill(mItemTops, 0);
            Arrays.fill(mItemBottoms, 0);

            if(mRestoreOffsets!=null)
            Arrays.fill(mRestoreOffsets, 0);
        }

        // TODO: consider repopulating in a deferred runnable instead
        // (so that successive changes may still be batched)
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInvalidated() {
    }
}
```

I have found a method to resolve this problem by remove the following code:

```
// reset list if position does not exist or id for position has changed
    if(mFirstPosition > mItemCount-1 || mAdapter.getItemId(mFirstPosition) != mFirstAdapterId){
        mFirstPosition = 0;
        Arrays.fill(mItemTops, 0);
        Arrays.fill(mItemBottoms, 0);

        if(mRestoreOffsets!=null)
        Arrays.fill(mRestoreOffsets, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Seems like `StaggeredGridView` does not extend Android's `AdapterView`, so what you observe might be just the way it behaves. AFAIK, standard GridView and ListView do not scroll to the top when you add data to adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` (without changing the adapter itself).

Comment: Your question is: When you scroll to bottom of StaggeredGridView, then it scroll back to top OR
When your adapter change you want it restores it's old position.
If the 1st one, could you so more your code for using StaggeredGridView

Comment: @deville   Thank you for your answer.I already found out how to resolve this problem through by modify onChanged method.

Comment: @hieuxit Thank you for your answer.What I mean is second one.When my adapter change,it scroll to top.But,I want it hold the position before adapter change.

Comment: @wayne you make my day. thank you