# staggered grid view adding new items dynamically (on scrollfinished listener)

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, staggered-gridview

I am using Android  Staggered Grid View in amy app and as it doesnot have any OnScrollListener.So i followed following tutorial to add one.

[Android - OnScrollListener for Staggered Grid View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851934/android-onscrolllistener-for-staggered-grid-view)

I am able to get the event of scrolling finished and also add add new items to adapter dynamically.
The new items are also reflected in grid.But the problem is whenever i add new items to grid.
The grid view position is placed at item 1.

Eg
I have 10 items in grid:A1 to 10

Once i receive event to load more ,i add more 10 items to adapter (A11 -A20) .They get added at bottom.
But the view is now placed at A1 (item 1).

How do i solve this?

Comment: did you notice `Calling notifyDataSetChanged() for StaggeredGridView Adapter case to reset the scroll position to 0 (Start of the Views).
Instead use PinterestLikeAdapterView` and want to solve it?

Comment: I want to use staggeredGrridView only as i have alredy developed by complete app using it.Does removing call to notifyDataSetChanges() help?

Comment: i do not know i just bring those sentences from the link you mentioned.

Comment: found this link :https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView/issues/11 will try out